# Slow Query when Joined View contains PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following view containing a PIVOT:

```
CREATE VIEW [vwPhoneNumberByPref]
AS
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT ObjectKey, ObjectTypeName,r_id,MaskedNumber FROM (
        SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectKey, ObjectTypeName ORDER BY preference) as r_id
        FROM vwPhoneNumberMasked  ) AS a WHERE r_id<=3
    )AS P
PIVOT(
    MAX(MaskedNumber) FOR r_id in ([1],[2],[3])
)AS Pvt
```

Which when I run it using `WHERE ObjectKey = 1234` returns a result instantly. When I use this query in a join though:

```
Select * 
from tblPerson p 
inner join 
    vwPhoneNumberByPref ph on p.PersonID = ph.ObjectKey
```

it takes about 10 seconds and in the execution plan, is doing a sort on over 200,000 rows.

When not used in a join, it is doing the "sort" on a single row. I tried doing the join using `CROSS APPLY` which makes it marginally faster, but still takes too long and is still sorting 200,000 odd rows.

How can I improve the performance?

---

Additional Info:

```
CREATE VIEW [vwPhoneNumberMasked] AS
SELECT ph.ObjectTypeName, ph.ObjectKey, dbo.ApplyMask(ph.PhoneNumber, pt.Mask), ph.Preference
FROM tblPhoneNumber ph inner join tblPhoneType pt on
ph.PhoneTypeName = pt.Name
WHERE ph.isDeleted = 0
GO

CREATE TABLE tblPhoneType
Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Mask varchar(20) NOT NULL
GO
```

There is an index on `tblPhoneNumber` on `ObjectTypeName, ObjectKey, Preference, isDeleted`

The function `dbo.ApplyMask` applies the Mask from PhoneType to PhoneNumber, the mask is `(##) #### ####`

I am not actually running `Select * from tblPerson`, But even running `SELECT PersonID from tblPerson INNER JOIN ....` causes the query to take ages. This was just for example.

Comment: Why are you using ROW_NUMBER function , Sorry but i do not see any need of assigning row numbers here , Correct me if i am wrong you can increase efficiency by removing assigning rownumbers.

Comment: @surajsingh The row number is being used to return only three values, these 3 values are then being converted into the columns in the pivot.

Comment: Can you post your table structure, the view definition of `vwPhoneNumberMasked` and show any indexes that you have?

Comment: I have aded dependant tables and indexes, sorry for omitting these.

Comment: @Molloch Can you post the create statement for the function `dbo.ApplyMask`?

Answer (score 0):

After you provided more information, I suggest you to try following. On the table `tblPhoneNumber` add index:

```
create index ix_tblPhoneNumber_1
    on tblPhoneNumber (isDeleted, ObjectKey, ObjectTypeName, Preference)
        include (PhoneNumber, PhoneTypeName)
```

On the table `tblPhoneType` add (if there are no) either

```
create unique clustered index ix_tblPhoneType
    on tblPhoneType (PhoneTypeName)
```

or

```
create unique index ix_tblPhoneType
    on tblPhoneType (PhoneTypeName) include (Mask)
```

Change your `vwPhoneNumberMasked` view as:

```
ALTER VIEW [vwPhoneNumberMasked] AS
SELECT ph.ObjectTypeName, ph.ObjectKey, mp.Value as MaskedNumber, ph.Preference
FROM tblPhoneNumber ph
    inner /*loop*/ join tblPhoneType pt on ph.PhoneTypeName = pt.Name
    cross apply ftMaskPhone(ph.PhoneNumber, pt.Mask) mp
WHERE ph.isDeleted = 0
```

Where `ftMaskPhone` is the one from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18244636/2523686)** (please use **Approach 2** version).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I am reviewing them, in the meantime I have added more info to the original question.