# Generating random string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random strings with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324063/generating-random-strings-with-t-sql)

I need to generate a random string with alpha and numeric characters inside a trigger.

The string must have a length of 15 and uppercase.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Does it need to be used in a single statement?

Comment: Possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74379410/3057246

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is far from an optimal solution, but it will work as specified:

```
select char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
      +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
      +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
      +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
      +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
```

Example output:

```
WCZOVRCIRELAJUT
```

Comment: If the length of 15 is set in stone, or if this is part of some test setup, than it's bulletproof.

Answer (score 2):

generate a GUID and take just the first 15 characters?

Generate a bunch of random numbers and translate to their ASCII values?

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea. The first 15 characters of a guid may not be so random... but then again, maybe they'll be random enough.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn:  Could maybe make it fancy and grab the first 6, then the last 5 with with the last 4 coming somewhere from the middle.

Comment: Part of the GUID is based on the MAC address would need to avoid that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that GUID is hashed. There is no fixed part of GUID that would stay the same even on same MAC.

Comment: I think `cast(cast(NEWID() as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))` is what you are suggesting in this answer. One potential issue is that there will be random special characters like ASCII 0 (null).