# Sql Password Generator - 8 characters, upper and lower and include a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a new password in TSQL which needs to be 8 characters (a-z) which have to include upper and lower characters as well as at least one number.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: do you want the server to randomly create a password for you?

Comment: This seems to meet all the stated requirements: select 'abc1DEF2' from myTable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
select cast((Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10) as varchar(1)) + 
       char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
       char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
       left(newid(),5)
from yourTable
```

Comment: Good answer to guarantee the password matches the requirements, however do note that because the structure is predictable the effective strength is much reduced.

Comment: Agree. OP has to decide if it's strong enough for him or not.

Comment: +1 Nice, answer. Pretty simple and working.

Answer (score 6):

Something to consider, a bit more complex:

```
SELECT      TOP 8
            SUBSTRING(tblSource.vsSource, tblValue.number + 1, 1) AS vsChar
FROM        (SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' AS vsSource) AS tblSource
            JOIN master..spt_values AS tblValue 
                ON tblValue.number < len(tblSource.vsSource)
WHERE       tblValue.type = 'P'
ORDER BY    NEWID()
```

but very random.

Comment: Updated version that worked for me: `select (
SELECT      TOP 8
            SUBSTRING(tblSource.vsSource, tblValue.number + 1, 1)
FROM        (SELECT 'abcdefhkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789+=-_~#$%*()' AS vsSource) AS tblSource
            JOIN master..spt_values AS tblValue 
                ON tblValue.number < len(tblSource.vsSource)
WHERE       tblValue.type = 'P'
ORDER BY    NEWID() 
FOR XML PATH ('')
)`

Comment: @AntonKruglov It did work just placed each value in a separate row. Still thanks for the re-work just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option that gives you very strongly random passwords. It uses a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) but other than that fairly straightforward.

```
declare @chars char(62), @bytes binary(8)
set @chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
set @bytes = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)

select SUBSTRING(@chars, (SUBSTRING(@bytes, n.Number, 1) % LEN(@chars)) + 1, 1)
from dbo.Numbers n
where n.Number between 1 and LEN(@bytes)
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: If the numbers table was a problem, spt_values as used by @Joseph Lee would be quite sufficient.

Comment: +1 Because "Undocumented system tables can be changed by Microsoft without warning, so you should avoid using them." and that's why your solution is better then the other one.

Comment: No good if using SQL Server 2005 or lower `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` was introduced in SQL Server 2008.