# How to make unique random alphanumeric sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to make unique random alphanumeric sequence to be the primary key for a database table.

Each char in the sequence is either a letter (a-z) or number (0-9)

Examples for what I want :

```
kl7jd6fgw
zjba3s0tr
a9dkfdue3
```

I want to make a function that could handle that task!

Comment: please add what all have you tried so far

Comment: You should not do this if your table is going to grow to any considerable size.  Primary keys should be int/bigint, or a GUID if you can afford the space/performance hit.  They shouldn't be a fairly short VARCHAR - lookups will be expensive and you're going to run out of keys.

Comment: This is a very bad Idea. Don't even think about using such things as a primary key. use an int/bigint column with identity property.

Comment: i will make a shorten link service that's why i need alphanumeric sequence !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [uniqueidentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx). This can be generated with the NEWID() function:

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

will return something like:

```
BE228C22-C18A-4B4A-9AD5-1232462F7BA9
```

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of NEWID() for this request is it limits the character pool to 0-9 and A-F. To define your own character pool, you have to role a custom solution.

This solution adapted from [Generating random strings with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324063/generating-random-strings-with-t-sql)

```
--Define list of characters to use in random string
DECLARE @CharPool VARCHAR(255)
SET @CharPool = '0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

--Store length of CharPool for use later
DECLARE @PoolLength TINYINT
SET @PoolLength = LEN(@CharPool) --36

--Define random string length
DECLARE @StringLength TINYINT
SET @StringLength = 9

--Declare target parameter for random string
DECLARE @RandomString VARCHAR(255)
SET @RandomString = ''

--Loop control variable
DECLARE @LoopCount TINYINT
SET @LoopCount = 0

--For each char in string, choose random char from char pool
WHILE(@LoopCount < @StringLength)
BEGIN
    SELECT @RandomString += SUBSTRING(@Charpool, CONVERT(int, RAND() * @PoolLength), 1)
    SELECT @LoopCount += 1
END

SELECT @RandomString
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4354

I must reiterate, however, that I agree with the others: this is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

**It is a *very* bad idea to use random strings as a primary key.**
It will effect performance as well as storage size, and you will be much better of using an int or a bigint with an identity property.

**However**, generating a random string in SQL maybe useful for other things, and this is why I offer this solution:

Create a table to hold permitted char values.
In my example the permitted chars are 0-9 and A-Z.

```
CREATE TABLE Chars (C char(1))

DECLARE @i as int = 0
WHILE @i < 10
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Chars (C) VALUES (CAST(@i as Char(1)))
  SET @i = @i+1
END

SET @i = 65
WHILE @i < 91
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Chars (C) VALUES (CHAR(@i))
  SET @i = @i+1
END
```

Then use this simple select statement to generate a random string from this table:

```
SELECT TOP 10 C AS [text()]
FROM Chars
ORDER BY NEWID()
FOR XML PATH('')
```

The advantages:

- You can easily control the allowed characters.
- The generation of a new string is a simple select statement and not manipulation on strings.

The disadvantages:

- This select results with an ugly name (i.e `XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B`). This is easily solved by setting the result into a local variable.
- Characters will only appear once in every string. This can easily be solved by adding union:

example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 C AS [text()]
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Chars
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Chars
  ) InnerSelect
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  FOR XML PATH('')
```

Another option is to use `STUFF` function instead of `As [Text()]` to eliminate those pesky XML tags:

```
SELECT STUFF((
 SELECT TOP 100 ''+ C 
 FROM Chars
 ORDER BY NEWID()
 FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') As RandomString;
```

This option doesn't have the disadvantage of the ugly column name, and can have an alias directly. Execution plan is a little different but it should not suffer a lot of performance lose.

[Play with it yourself in this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea7a5/38)

If there are any more advantages / disadvantages you think of please leave a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**NewID() Function will generate unique numbers.So i have incremented them with loop and picked up the combination of alpha numeric characters using Charindex and Left functions**

```
;with list as 
    (
        select 1 as id,newid() as val
             union all
        select id + 1,NEWID()
        from    list   
        where   id + 1 < 100
    ) 
    select ID,left(val, charindex('-', val) - 2) from list
    option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.