# SQL - generate alphanumeric string with specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, ascii

I need to find out how to generate an alphanumeric string that follows the format like in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324063/generating-random-strings-with-t-sql) which I'm currently using, except it has to be in the following format:

Vowel + consonant + vowel + consonant + 4-digit number

For example ABAB1111 or IJUZ9236.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: your question is still not clear.why you will want to generate series with ABAB.......and why not with something else.when it will change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this steps:

Generate a `vowels`(`A,E...`) table ,  `consonants` (`B,C..`) table and  `numbers` (`1,2,..`) table .

Then use this query:

```
SELECT  (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM vowels ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM consonants ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM vowels ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM consonants ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM numbers ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM numbers ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM numbers ORDER BY newid()) +
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM numbers ORDER BY newid())
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want a random string.  Something like this should work:

```
with v as (
      select 'A' as c union all select 'E' union all . . . 
     ),
     c as (
      select 'B' as c union all select 'C' union all . . .
     ),
     d as (
      select '0' as c union all select '1' union all . . .
     )
select ((select top 1 c from v order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from c order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from v order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from c order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from d order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from d order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from d order by newid()) +
        (select top 1 c from d order by newid())
       );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I'm using this right now and it works as a query, but when I try using it as a Stored Procedure and scalar-valued function it throws up syntax errors even though no red lines appear. I have a screenshot here: http://imgur.com/Y1FzZhD

Comment: @Alycus . . . Put semicolons at the end of each statement.

Answer (score 1):

Using temp tables as example data i'd do it like this;

```
CREATE TABLE #Vowels (Vowel varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #Vowels VALUES ('A'),('E'),('I'),('O'),('U')

CREATE TABLE #Consonants (Consonant varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #Consonants VALUES ('B'),('C'),('D'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')

CREATE TABLE #Numbers (Numbers varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #Numbers VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)

SELECT
v1.Vowel + c1.Consonant + v2.Vowel + c2.Consonant + n1.Numbers + n2.Numbers + n3.Numbers + n4.Numbers AS Result

FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Vowel FROM #Vowels ORDER BY NEWID()) v1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Consonant FROM #Consonants ORDER BY NEWID()) c1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Vowel FROM #Vowels ORDER BY NEWID()) v2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Consonant FROM #Consonants ORDER BY NEWID()) c2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Numbers FROM #Numbers ORDER BY NEWID()) n1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Numbers FROM #Numbers ORDER BY NEWID()) n2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Numbers FROM #Numbers ORDER BY NEWID()) n3
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Numbers FROM #Numbers ORDER BY NEWID()) n4

DROP TABLE #Consonants
DROP TABLE #Numbers
DROP TABLE #Vowels
```

The result comes out like this but with different values each time you run it.

```
Result
AQOF7641
```

If you are running this a number of times, it would make sense to make proper tables containing your vowels, consonants and number. It would reduce the (admittedly small) cost of this query.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH letters as
(
  SELECT 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz' c, 'aeiou' v
)
,CTE as
(
  SELECT
    SUBSTRING(v, CAST(rand()*5 as int)+1, 1)+
    SUBSTRING(c, CAST(rand()*21 as int)+1, 1)+
    SUBSTRING(v, CAST(rand()*5 as int)+1, 1)+
    SUBSTRING(c, CAST(rand()*21 as int)+1, 1)+
    right(10000+ CAST(rand()*10000 as int),4) x
  FROM letters
)
SELECT x
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @AlphaString VARCHAR(200) = NULL;

WITH
    CTE_Digits AS (
    SELECT TOP 255
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) AS RowNum
    FROM
        sys.all_columns a
    CROSS JOIN
        sys.all_columns b),
    CTE_Types AS (
    SELECT
        CHAR(RowNum) AS Digit,
        CASE
            WHEN RowNum < 58 THEN 'D'
            WHEN CHAR(RowNum) IN ('A','E','I','O','U') THEN 'V'
            ELSE 'C'
        END AS CharType
    FROM
        CTE_Digits
    WHERE
        RowNum BETWEEN 48 AND 57
        OR RowNum BETWEEN 65 AND 90),
    CTE_List AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CharType ORDER BY NEWID()) AS NewRow
    FROM
        CTE_Types),
    CTE_Ordered AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE CharType
            WHEN 'V' THEN 2
            WHEN 'C' THEN 3
            WHEN 'D' THEN 7
        END * NewRow AS DigitOrder
    FROM
        CTE_List
    WHERE
        (NewRow < 5
        AND CharType = 'D')
        OR NewRow < 3)
SELECT @AlphaString = 
(SELECT
    CAST(Digit AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM
    CTE_Ordered
ORDER BY
    DigitOrder
FOR XML PATH(''));

SELECT @AlphaString;
```