# Generate Random ID that don't already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I have a table containing IDs and they are all in 3-letter words. How do I use `SELECT` statement that returns a randomly generated 3 letter ID that does not yet exist in the current table and `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789` are the only characters that can be used?

I would like to provide something I have in mind but I totally have no idea how to do this. Thank you so much.

Comment: You could try using `HASHBYTES` - though you will get collisions - but you will with any RNG.

Comment: you will need to store all generated IDs (obviously) in a permanent table and check for existence. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324063/generating-random-strings-with-t-sql

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes Sir, there is a table that contains the IDs. How do I Select generateID() where generateID() is not in..... Something like that?

Comment: check the link I posted ....

Comment: @chris_techno25 you don't need to call anyone sir here... we're all equal...

Comment: @DaleK But some of us are more equal than others... _especially_ if we're talking about JavaScript, what with `==` vs `===` yaknow?

Comment: @DaleK I'm certainly not an equal to most people here lol. I have limited knowledge.

Comment: @chris_techno25 no 2 people here have the same level of knowledge, but as people we are equals and no deference is necessary, nor is it welcomed by most of us.

Comment: What if Sir Patrick Stewart or Sir Tim Berners-Lee posted on StackOverflow though?

Comment: Then you ask them how they wish to be addressed I guess

Comment: There are two ways, either 1) write a loop that generates a random value until it doesn't exist or 2) generate all values once and then pick the one that isn't exist already. The first idea is bad because it might take a while to get a match, the second should be good if you only have 3 characters